# Micronaut Informer

Tags: kubernetes, micronaut

I'm trying to use micronaut kubernetes informer like what they explained in documentation . this is my code

```
@Singleton
@Informer(apiType = V1ConfigMap.class, apiListType = 
V1ConfigMapList.class)
public class ConfigMapInformer implements 
 ResourceEventHandler<V1ConfigMap> {

@Override
public void onAdd(V1ConfigMap obj) {
    System.err.println("add config map");
 }

@Override
public void onUpdate(V1ConfigMap oldObj, V1ConfigMap newObj) {
    System.err.println("update configmap");
 }

@Override
public void onDelete(V1ConfigMap obj, boolean deletedFinalStateUnknown) 
 {
 }
}
```

And i'm using minikube for runing this application.
but after changing ConfigMaps nothing happens

this is my build.gradle dependencies section
[image]

and these are logs of pod

```
←[36m06:16:02.327←[0;39m ←[1;30m[pool-3-thread-1]←[0;39m 
←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m ←[35mi.m.k.c.KubernetesConfigMapWatcher←[0;39m - 
 PropertySource modified by ConfigMap: employee
 ←[36m06:16:02.327←[0;39m ←[1;30m[pool-3-thread-1]←[0;39m ←[34mINFO 
 ←[0;39m ←[35mi.m.context.DefaultBeanContext←[0;39m - Reading bootstrap 
 environment configuration
 ←[36m06:16:02.328←[0;39m ←[1;30m[pool-3-thread-1]←[0;39m ←[34mINFO 
 ←[0;39m ←[35mi.m.d.c.c.DistributedPropertySourceLocator←[0;39m - 
  Resolved 1 configuration sources from client: 
  compositeConfigurationClient(kubernetes)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess without having the access to the source code. But there's an example informer app in the micronaut-kubernetes github https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kubernetes/tree/master/examples/micronaut-kubernetes-informer , check it out.

What could also help is complete `build.gradle` snippet.

Comment: thanks, I forgot that singleton got initialized lazily in Micronauts. using `@Context` instead of `@Singleton` solves my problem.